# Is NHibernate LINQ stable and do all NHibernate bolt on projects allow it

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have been a long time user of Subsonic due to its ease of use and LINQ integration.

I now have to use something else because I need to be able to use Oracle.

I have 2 databases with the same schema therefore I want to have 1 set of POCO's and then change a connection string to switch between SQL & Oracle depending on the requirements.

Is this possible firstly, is LINQ fully functioning and stable in NHibernate and do Castle ActiveRecord and Fluent Hibernate allow the LINQ querying?

Comment: Simply yes, it's functioning, you can see the test scenarios in source code of NHiebrnate Project(esp Linq Part), but what I said is about NHibernate not fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is stable.
2. It is not fully functioning, and it is not planned to be fully functioning. I don't think there exists linq providers supporting 100% everything. The question should be: "Is it fully function for the queries you need to execute?" (The answer to that question would be yes in 99% of the cases)
3. You can find reported bugs/missing features in J[ira](http://216.121.112.228/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project+%3D+NH+AND+resolution+%3D+Unresolved+AND+component+%3D+%22Linq+Provider%22+ORDER+BY+priority+DESC&mode=hide)
4. Fluent NHhibernate doesn't do any querying, just mapping. Castle active record doesn't query either. The linq namespace does not have a reference to active record or fluent and vise versa.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: Castle ActiveRecord *does* have a little layer on top of NHibernate Criteria, HQL, and LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't classify the NHibernate LINQ implementation as stable yet. The LINQ provider is still fairly young, so chance of hitting an unsupported query scneario still may be considerable in my opinion. However, other NHibernate query options are plentiful to workaround any issues the LINQ provider might throw up.